# Textual subscript in math mode

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

I want to put some short words in certain subscripts when I am in math mode, for example:

```
\[W_{total} = \sum{W_i}\]
```

but I think LaTeX understands this as the product of `t`, `o`, `t`, `a` and `l`.

Is in any case this way the right way, or is there any other one?

By the way, I have tried

```
\[W_{\text{total}}\]
```

<strike>but it is not fine for me. (A bit ugly)</strike> Forget that.

Comment: Could you elaborate why you find it ugly.

Comment: @Caramdir bah, I made a mistake. Forget that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you have tried is the right way. You can simplify it slightly and play with other fonts:

```
$$ W_\textrm{total} = \sum_i W_i $$
```

To make it prettier I'd suggest to think about the use of variables and indices in your work. For example, you could reserve `W` (without index) for the total which is the sum of `w_i` (lowercase w). This way you can avoid long subscripts.

Comment: As this is a LaTeX question, stick with `\[ ... \]` rather than `$$ ... $$`. Also, I'd recommend `W_{\textrm{total}}` with braces around the subscript text.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; your suggestion about subscripts was useful too :) By the way, is there any difference between `\textrm` and `\text`?

Comment: @Juan Yes, `\textrm` make the text whatever is defined as the serifed text font.  `\text` respects the local text environment.  So `\sffamily $W_\text{total}$` will give you a sans serifed subscript, while `\sffamily $W_\textrm{total}$` will still give you a serifed subscript.