# Which command should I use for textual subscripts in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, best-practices, subscripts

Textual subscripts like in `W_{total}` should be typeset in an upright text font (so that code isn't good practice), as has been [discussed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9556/textual-subscript-in-math-mode) in [various](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33120/should-subscripts-in-math-mode-be-upright) [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9333/redefine-underscore-to-produce-roman-subscript) [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12812/text-in-subscript). Now there are several ways to *achieve* this, and I'm somewhat confused which I should use:

1. `W_{\rm total}` is nice and short, and appears to work in all circumstances, but I expect LaTeX people will frown upon it `:-)` Is there any good reason against this?
2. `W_{\mathrm{total}}` – is this the LaTeX equivalent of the `\rm` approach?
3. `W_{\textnormal{total}}` [sounds reasonable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75141) as `total` is text and not math ...
4. In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98011), Ulrike Fischer suggests a more complicated approach.
5. Even `W_{\operatorname{total}}` appears to work, but it seems inappropriate.

Note: I always assume here that `amsmath` is loaded.

I've already asked some questions above, but my main question is: which of these options is the best practice for textual subscripts?

---

Let me point out why I haven't mentioned `\text`, `\textrm` or `\textup` above. Those commands (mostly) keep the font of the context they're used in, e.g., in an italic context, `\text` and `\textrm` would give italic subscripts, and all three yield bold subscripts in a bold context.

Final note: This question is similar to, but not the same as all those [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88794/difference-between-mathrm-operatorname-and-text) about the [differences](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70632/difference-between-various-methods-for-producing-text-in-math-mode) between [`\mbox`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3415/what-is-the-correct-way-of-embedding-text-into-math-mode), [`\text`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19502/is-there-a-preference-of-when-to-use-text-and-mathrm), [`\textrm`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22350/difference-between-textrm-and-mathrm), [`\mathrm`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98008/is-mathrm-really-preferable-to-text), [`\operatorname`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48459/whats-the-difference-between-mathrm-and-operatorname) that have been asked before. Maybe it's still a duplicate ...

Comment: I think it eventually boils down to: What font should _textual_ subscripts have depending (or not depending) on the outer text mode (rm vs sf, up vs it, bf vs md, …)? Which, in my eyes, is less a TeX than more a typography question. Second question is: When using different fonts for text and math mode: Should textual subscript use the text font (as it is text) or the upright version of the math font (fits better). And if we are talking _textual_ subscript both `\rm` and `\mathrm` are out of the question because they will render `-` as a minus sign not a dash.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: I'm asking about options #1 to #5, which is a TeX question. Of course you're right that there's a typography question behind it. And: good point about the `-`!! (But otherwise, for the standard CM fonts, the upright text and math fonts are just the same, aren't they?)

Comment: Yes, for the standard CM fonts there is no real difference between math and text font, and I totally agree with egreg’s answer (`\textnormal`: text (`-` and space), roman, upright, medium). If one has different fonts for math and text they should fit well anyway and `\textnormal` should still produce a good-looking output.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

First of all, the problem presents for *textual* subscripts, such as those used in physics to distinguish between vectors with the same name (say a force) by a subscripted label that should go in upright type. Textual subscripts are used in many other fields.

In what follows, `amsmath` is assumed.

1. `$W_{\rm total}$` is totally wrong as it relies on a deprecated command that classes don't need to define (and indeed some don't).
2. `$W_{\mathrm{total}}$` is the correct form of the above. Limitations: spaces are gobbled and hyphens become minus signs.
3. `$W_{\textnormal{total}}$` uses the main roman font of the document, no matter the context; the argument is typeset as text at the correct size.
4. `$W_{\mathup{total}}$` (with [Ulrike Fischer's definition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98011)) has one advantage over `\mathrm`, since it uses `\familydefault`, but the same limitations.
5. `$W_{\operatorname{total}}$` is like using a sledgehammer for killing a fly. It's the same as `\mathrm`, but hyphens don't become minus signs.
6. `$W_{\text{total}}$` might seem ideal, but it changes font according to the context, so the subscript would appear in italics in a theorem statement.

Therefore, form 3 seems the most natural. Notice that braces are not really necessary, except in case 5.

To be honest, for single words `\mathrm` (or `\mathup`) is more efficient, as `\textnormal` uses `\mathchoice` and typesets four times the subscript in different sizes. However, the overhead is almost negligible with modern machines and uniformity is to be preferred to efficiency, when it doesn't slow the workflow in a significant way.

If, for some reasons, one wants that textual subscripts are typeset in upright type, but keeping the current font family, for instance because some parts of the document use sans serif type also for math (which I don't agree with), a modified version of `\textnormal` can be used:

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textnormalf}[1]{% f for "keep the family
  \text{\usefont{\f@encoding}{\f@family}{m}{n}#1}%
}
\makeatother
```

Here `\f@encoding` and `\f@family` are the current output font encoding and font family, as stored by LaTeX at each (text) font change; with font series `m` and font shape `n` we're choosing upright medium type.

Of course, a more meaningful name for `\textnormalf` should be chosen according to its usage and semantics.

Comment: One thing I don't understand yet: why do you say `$W_\textnormal{total}$` uses the main _roman_ font of the document? If the main font of the document _isn't_ roman, then `\textnormal` won't use roman either, will it? (I think I still understand the part about `\textnormalf`, where you assume changes of the family inside the document.)

Comment: Interesting point about `\rm`: I knew it's deprecated, but I didn't know that there are classes which don't define the command!

Comment: @HendrikVogt With "main roman font" I mean the default document font (which is usually roman).

Comment: @egreg Do you still stand by the advice to omit braces around subscripts?  I remember you saying otherwise in the past year or so but I didn't want to edit without confirmation.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Added the missing braces

Comment: Despite the deprecation the `\rm` command, it remains useful as the most concise and thus often most readable and easiest to write variant. When looking at `x_{\rm b}` vs `x_{\mathrm{b}}` the latter seems like an odd design choice. If preferred, these commands can be reenabled where not provided by `\DeclareOldFontCommand`, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57109/what-exactly-does-declareoldfontcommand-and-declarerobustcommand-do .

Comment: @kdb There are people who like [this bycicle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penny-farthing)

Comment: shouldn't the case `$W_{\textup{total}}$` be discussed as well?

Comment: @pluton It suffers the same problem as `\text`, because in a boldface context `\textup{total}` would be typeset bold.

Comment: @egreg Ok I see. I will have to change them all then!

Comment: In some styles, `$\textnormal{min}$` uses a different font than `$\min$`.

Comment: If one uses `unicode-math` is `\symup` acceptable for math mode text, as in text sub/superscripts?

Comment: What makes `\operatorname` a sledgehammer? Looking at the answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48459/whats-the-difference-between-mathrm-and-operatorname/48463) it seems to be quite useful although perhaps not for subscripts specifically. Is this a more general warning not to use it, in your answer?

Comment: @lucidbrot Because `\mathrm` is much more efficient and most of the times you don’t have an operator there.

Comment: Except if using e.g. the default beamer theme, where `\operatorname` will provide the correct font and `\mathrm` will not (although it probably should).

Answer (score 0):

Below I am posting a clip from ISO 80000-1:2007.

[image]

In the description, the term *roman* is used as a synonym for *upright*, not for *serif*. Furthermore, in the examples below one can clearly see that the sans serif font of the main text is transferred to the subscripts. This actually makes sense, because `gas` in the text should have exactly the same font as `g` in the subscript, apart from the fact that `g` is (always) upright.

My conclusion is that if one wants to follow ISO 80000 standard, the most appropriate solution is

- `\textnormal` to return to the default global text font (here I assume that default text is always upright)
- `\textup` (possibly combined with `\textmd` to turn off bold) to return back to the local upright text font