# How to multiply a fraction

Tags: equations, fractions

I have an equation in which inside I have a fraction. I want to put a number (3.3) that indicates multiplication.

```
\begin{eqnarray}

\phantom{0}LOD = \frac{\phantom{0}S}{N} = 0.1\phantom{0} \si{\ng/\uL}
\end{eqnarray}
```

I tried  `\phantom{0}LOD = $3.3$\frac{\phantom{0}S}{N} = 0.1\phantom{0}`
but it doesn't compile.

Comment: you shouldn't use `eqnarray`. See `amsmath` and `mathtools`. The `align`-environment is especially useful.

Comment: Just `3.3\frac{...}{...}`: what's the problem?

Comment: What's the significance, or purpose, of the three `\phantom{0}` directives?

Comment: I am using \phantom{0} to align two equations, the one beneath the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are after? Your problem was in the dollar signs around `3.3`. You don't need to do add dollar signs when already inside a math-environment. Besides, `3.3` can be written both in normal text mode and in math.

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \phantom{0}LOD = 3.3 \cdot \frac{\phantom{0}S}{N} = 0.1\phantom{0} \si{\ng\per\uL}
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

### Suggestions

- Don't use `eqnarray`. It has lots of problems. See [The TUGboat-article by Lars Madsen](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb33-1/tb103madsen.pdf). Use `mathtools`, which loads `amstools`, both of which has some really great functions for writing math. Especially `align`-environment is really useful. For single line equations, use `equations`-environment.
- Use `siunitx` for getting consistent spacing and notation. I like to write all numerals with it, it makes it so much easier to change the look of everything.
- You don't need all those `\phantom`-stuff, most likely.
- When writing words or abbreviations in math, use `\mathrm`, otherwise, `LOD` would mathematically read out as `L · O · D`. See [Which command should I use for textual subscripts in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98406/which-command-should-i-use-for-textual-subscripts-in-math-mode?lq=1)

**Suggested Output**

[image]

**Suggested Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol} % or fraction, among others
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    LOD = \num{3.3} \cdot \frac{S}{N} = \SI{0.1}{\ng\per\uL}
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Avoid `eqnarray`!](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb33-1/tb103madsen.pdf)

Comment: thank you, @clemens . I just couldn't remember where I've read it.

Comment: I think it's more "canonical" to write `\SI[per-mode=symbol]{0.1}{\nano\gram\per\micro\liter}` than `0.1\phantom{0} \si{\ng/\uL}`.

Comment: Personally, I always do that, but I have only done it because I think in words, and not the actual letters. But some other people really like thinking in the abbreviations, and therefore writing it like that. I am sure it must be confusing, but I guess its a matter of taste.

Comment: I think @Mico's main point was that `\SI` (capital letters) is for writing a number with a unit, whereas `\si` (lower case) is for writing a standalone unit (e.g. in the axis labels of a plot). Here there is a number with a unit, so one should use `\SI{0.1}{\ng\per\ul}` (using abbreviations or not). I also think that `\phantom{0}` gives a too large space, `\,` would be better, but `\SI` already does that.  Finally, one could point out that using `align` for a single-line equation should be avoided (there is a question about this somewhere), the `equation` environment would be better.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I guess I could have been a bit more clear about this in my suggestions, both for `\SI` and `align`.

Comment: I have to admit I didn't really read the text, I only looked at your code example (where you still have `\si`), so I didn't see that you had recommended `\SI` already. The first `\phantom` also seems very pointless, though we don't have the whole context.

Comment: Yes, the \phantom seems pointless but I was trying to align two equations, so it came handy