# How do I get upright text as a subscript?

Tags: subscripts

I want my subscript to be upright, so T and not as in `$T$`. How do I do it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
How can I get the subscript in $\Pr_T$ as T and not as in $T$?
\end{document}
```

Comment: $\Pr_{\mathrm T}$.

Comment: I usually use `$\Pr_{\text{T}}$` (with `amsmath`). It helps if I need something unusual like cyrillic letters in a subscript.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98406/15925

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally the effect is obtained using `\mathrm` using the `amsmath` package. 
I wouldn't recommend `\text`.

In fact, `\mathrm` is the correct way since it uses the upright font for the mathematical environment, while `\text` resorts using the *current text font,* which can cause the `\text` part to be e.g. in italics if the current text is set in italic.

See for example this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
I use \texttt{text} \( Pr_{\text{T}}\) and I use \texttt{mathrm}  \( Pr_{\mathrm{T}}\) 
\bigskip

{
\itshape
I use \texttt{text} \( Pr_{\text{T}}\) and I use \texttt{mathrm}  \( Pr_{\mathrm{T}}\) 
}

\end{document}
```

With result:

[image]

It's clear that the correct way to **always obtain mathematical roman** is `\mathrm`. Also, the `\text` command is conceived to typeset some text in the equations, strings such as "as given by" or "as you can see in".

From the documentation of `amsmath`

> The main use of the command \text is for words or phrases in a display. It is very similar to the LATEX command \mbox in its effects, but has a couple of advantages. If you want a word or phrase of text in a subscript, you can type ...*{\text{word or phrase}}, which is slightly easier than the \mbox equivalent: ...*{\mbox{\scriptsize word or phrase}}. The other advantage is the more descriptive name.

Comment: How can I also have T bold as in \textbf{T} or $\mathbf{T}$ in the subscript?

Comment: I solved that using: \documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
I use \texttt{text} \( Pr_{\text{T}}\) and I use \texttt{mathrm}  \( Pr_{\mathrm{T}}\) 
\bigskip

{
\itshape
I use \texttt{text} \( Pr_{\text{T}}\) and I use \texttt{mathrm}  \( Pr_{\mathrm{\mathbf{T}}}\) 
}

\end{document}

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal sure

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a `\text{}` tag in your subscript,so in your example it would be `$\Pr_{\text{T}}$`.

Edit: I forgot to mention that in order for this to work you have to include the  `amsmath`package.

Comment: `text` isn't always outputting upright fonts

Comment: @Moriambar Yes you are right, it's applying the current text style to the subscript.

Comment: You can use `\textrm`…