# Use upright text in \text within theorem

Tags: amsmath, theorems

How to make the text in `\text` to be automatically upright in a theorem environment?

For example, I want to use these codes to get the following effect:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
  This is a theorem.
  \[ F_\text{left}=F_\text{right} \]
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Actually, I use `\textup` to get this effect here.)

**Update:** The question [Which command should I use for textual subscripts in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98406/136923) may be helpful.

Comment: Most likely you need a theoremstyle and `\upshape`, but this is untested

Comment: I mean that the normal text should be still italic, but in math mode, the text to be upright. In my example, "This is a theorem" is italic, where "left" and "right" is upright.

Comment: As you can see this is **not** the intended use for the `\text` command. It should be used for textual comments in displayed math, nothing else. Sadly many users misuse it like this. `\textup` or `\textnormal ` is this correct choice in this case.

Comment: But I think the "left" and "right" here are just **textual comments**. What I want is that a simple `F_\text{left}` can have the same effect with `F_\text{\upshape left}`.

Comment: The macro `\textup` is exactly what you should use; or, even better, `\mathrm` for single words.

Comment: @egreg So can you give an example of when to use `\text`?

Comment: These are not textual comments, they are named indices. They always have to be upright, and `\text` is allowed to be italic when the context is italic, thus should clearly not be used for textual indices.

Comment: Example of correct use: `f(x) =1 \qquad\text{for all $x>5$} `. Here for all should match the surrounding text it should not be always upright. The fact that it follows the surrounding text also explains why you should not use `\text{Log} ` for a function name.